# Powershell 1.0 - Iterate through folders with a ps1 file

Tags: loops, powershell

How would I iterate through folders with a .ps1 file? I have

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\apple\login.aspx
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\orange\login.aspx
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\banana\login.aspx
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\pear\login.aspx
```

I just came across this example:

```
# PowerShell Foreach File Example
Clear-Host
$Path = "C:\Windows\System32\*.dll"
Get-ChildItem $Path | Foreach-Object {
Write-Host $_.Name
}
```

So I would do:

```
# PowerShell Foreach File Example
Clear-Host
$Path = "C:\Windows\System32\*.dll" //here is where I'm not sure of what to do
Get-ChildItem $Path | Foreach-Object {
//insert stuff
}
```

In my "not sure of what to do" comment how would I change it so it would loop through different sub-directories of windows?

Comment: Basically, you're asking for a tutorial on Powershell loop constructs.  There's lots of those available on the net.

Comment: @mjolinor that's not how I read this - he's asking for how to recurse into subdirectories, a very common need with this command that is admittedly slightly difficult to find for people not familiar with powershell's structure

Comment: @GeorgeMauer I didn't read it that way (he's got a specific list of folders and is explicitly asking about using a loop). I could be wrong about that, and you may have provided the answer.

Comment: I've searched and searched through sites and can't find anything like I want to help me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm 90% sure that the `Recurse` parameter is available on Powershell 1. So

```
ls c:\windows\system32 -Recurse -Include *.dll
```

`ls` and `dir` are both aliases for `Get-ChildItem`